# unable to run a cookbook chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm trying to run my cookbook "example" but I'm not able to. I'm testing it before running it on  my node machines and I'm getting this error below. Here is my list of dependecy which I believe should be correct. I have a cookbook example and a default.rb which has the include statement of the recipe's I would like to run.

[dependency photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZbXX.png)

error below.

```
cs@pop-os:~/experimetns/chef-repo/cookbooks$ chef-client -z --runlist "recipe[example]" --why-run
[2022-02-05T17:14:15-08:00] INFO: Started Chef Infra Zero at chefzero://localhost:1 with repository at /home/cs/experimetns/chef-repo (One version per cookbook)
Chef Infra Client, version 17.6.18
Patents: https://www.chef.io/patents
Infra Phase starting
[2022-02-05T17:14:15-08:00] INFO: *** Chef Infra Client 17.6.18 ***
[2022-02-05T17:14:15-08:00] INFO: Platform: x86_64-linux
[2022-02-05T17:14:15-08:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 37058
[2022-02-05T17:14:17-08:00] ERROR: shard_seed: Failed to get dmi property serial_number: is dmidecode installed?
[2022-02-05T17:14:18-08:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to [#<Chef::RunList::RunListItem:0x00000000035a6588 @version=nil, @type=:recipe, @name="example">] from CLI options
[2022-02-05T17:14:18-08:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[example]]
[2022-02-05T17:14:18-08:00] INFO: Run List expands to [example]
[2022-02-05T17:14:18-08:00] INFO: Starting Chef Infra Client Run for jtagaca
[2022-02-05T17:14:18-08:00] INFO: Running start handlers
[2022-02-05T17:14:18-08:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
Resolving cookbooks for run list: ["example"]
[2022-02-05T17:14:18-08:00] INFO: Loading cookbooks [httpd@0.1.0]
Synchronizing cookbooks:
[2022-02-05T17:14:18-08:00] INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/httpd/CHANGELOG.md in the cache.
[2022-02-05T17:14:18-08:00] INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/httpd/chefignore in the cache.
[2022-02-05T17:14:18-08:00] INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/httpd/LICENSE in the cache.
[2022-02-05T17:14:18-08:00] INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/httpd/recipes/install_httpd.rb in the cache.
[2022-02-05T17:14:18-08:00] INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/httpd/metadata.rb in the cache.
[2022-02-05T17:14:18-08:00] INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/httpd/README.md in the cache.
[2022-02-05T17:14:18-08:00] INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/httpd/recipes/default.rb in the cache.
[2022-02-05T17:14:18-08:00] INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/httpd/recipes/adduser.rb in the cache.
[2022-02-05T17:14:18-08:00] INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/httpd/recipes/start_service.rb in the cache.
  - httpd (0.1.0)
Installing cookbook gem dependencies:
Compiling cookbooks...
Loading Chef InSpec profile files:
Loading Chef InSpec input files:
Loading Chef InSpec waiver files:
[2022-02-05T17:14:18-08:00] WARN: MissingCookbookDependency:
Recipe `httpd::adduser` is not in the run_list, and cookbook 'httpd'
is not a dependency of any cookbook in the run_list.  To load this recipe,
first add a dependency on cookbook 'httpd' in the cookbook you're
including it from in that cookbook's metadata.


================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /home/cs/experimetns/chef-repo/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/httpd/recipes/default.rb
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound
----------------------------------
Cookbook httpd not found. If you're loading httpd from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata

Cookbook Trace: (most recent call first)
----------------------------------------
  /home/cs/experimetns/chef-repo/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/httpd/recipes/default.rb:7:in `from_file'

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/home/cs/experimetns/chef-repo/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/httpd/recipes/default.rb:

  1:  #
  2:  # Cookbook:: httpd
  3:  # Recipe:: default
  4:  #
  5:  # Copyright:: 2022, The Authors, All Rights Reserved.
  6:  
  7>> include_recipe 'httpd::adduser'
  8:  include_recipe 'httpd::install_httpd'
  9:  include_recipe 'httpd::start_service'
 10:  

System Info:
------------
chef_version=17.6.18
platform=pop
platform_version=20.04
ruby=ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [x86_64-linux]
program_name=/usr/bin/chef-client
executable=/opt/chef-workstation/bin/chef-client


Running handlers:
[2022-02-05T17:14:18-08:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2022-02-05T17:14:18-08:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Infra Phase failed. 0 resources would have been updated
[2022-02-05T17:14:18-08:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /home/cs/experimetns/chef-repo/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2022-02-05T17:14:18-08:00] FATAL: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-02-05T17:14:18-08:00] FATAL: PLEASE PROVIDE THE CONTENTS OF THE stacktrace.out FILE (above) IF YOU FILE A BUG REPORT
[2022-02-05T17:14:18-08:00] FATAL: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-02-05T17:14:18-08:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: Cookbook httpd not found. If you're loading httpd from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
cs@pop-os:~/experimetns/chef-repo/cookbooks$ ^C
```

Comment: Are you trying to use the community (supermarket) cookbook for `httpd`? Have you defined dependency for it in your cookbook's `metadata.rb`?